# How to align expanded widgets in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why does the 1st two work but not the 3rd?? what's the alternative to add vertical divider with height that stretch to the max height of the row?

These 2 works

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text('Kicukiro'),
        ),
        Container(width: 1,color: Colors.black,height: double.infinity,),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: Text('Kicukiro'),
          )
      ],
    )
```

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('Kicukiro'),
          ),
        ),
        // Container(width: 1,color: Colors.black,height: double.infinity,),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Text('Kicukiro'),
            ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

this does not work

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('Kicukiro'),
          ),
        ),
        Container(width: 1,color: Colors.black,height: double.infinity,),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Text('Kicukiro'),
            ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Please paste the code as text, it will be easier to reproduce for us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this and it will work

```
 IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                     Expanded(
                       child: Container(
                           child: const Text("Kicukiro", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 52),)),
                     ),
                    Container(color:Colors.black, width: 1),
                     Expanded(
                       child: Container(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                           child: const Text("Kicukiro", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 52),)),
                     ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last screenshot please add the `Container` under an `Expanded` widget. Use `children` property under `Row` widget.

Here is an example code

```
 Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is question',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: FlatButton(
            //textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text(
              'True',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: FlatButton(
            //textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              'False',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        )),
      ]
```

Comment: yeah but i don't the widget to be expanded as it will mess up the width of that middle widget. check the code

Comment: Did you try to use Sizebox() widget for working as a divider?

Comment: I am trying to keep that height dynamic and relative to the Row height

Answer (score 0):

The third is true, in fact, its existence in an `SingleChildScrollView` has created a problem
It is fixed by putting `SizedBox` in `Row` and giving it height
The reason for this problem is the size of the height of the `container`, which is determined by `double.infinity` and due to its presence in an `SingleChildScrollView`, it continues indefinitely and an error was created.

```
   SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 250,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
               Expanded(child: Container(child: Text("Kicukiro"))),
               Container(
                 width: 1,color: Colors.black,height: double.infinity,
               ),
               Expanded(child: Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                   child: Text("Kicukiro"))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The height is actually the problem, I would have guessed that Expanded inside a Row instead of Column wouldn't cause height errors. And I want the height to stay dynamic.

Comment: I get that the height grows indefinitely downward but why is it not a problem on the 1st piece of code though?

Comment: I tested the first one and it got a bug. Put it in `SingleChi..` again

Comment: the middle Container is supposed to be a vertical divider with fixed width but dynamic height. Also `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` is throwing errors too.